# AVPlayer instance always nil when using stream

Tags: swift, flutter, avplayer

I'm trying to implement `EventChannel` on swift to flutter side. So this what I am doing,

How I registered event channel,

```
public class SwiftMusicPlayer: NSObject, FlutterPlugin {
    
    final var audioPlayer = AudioPlayer()
    
    struct Constants {
        static let methodChannelName = "MethodChannel"
        static let durationEventChannel = "durationEventChannel"
           ...
    }
    
    public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
        let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: Constants.methodChannelName, binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
        let instance = SwiftMusicPlayer()
        registrar.addMethodCallDelegate(instance, channel: channel)
        let durationChannel = FlutterEventChannel(name: Constants.durationEventChannel, binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
        durationChannel.setStreamHandler(AudioPlayer())
    }

// The method calls
 public func handle(_ call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {

   let args = call.arguments as? Dictionary<String, Any>
        switch call.method {

       case Constants.preparePlayer:
            audioPlayer.preparePlayer(path: args?[Constants.path] as? String, volume: args?[Constants.volume] as? Double,result: result)
            break
        case Constants.startPlayer:
            audioPlayer.startPlayer(result: result)
            break
        case Constants.pausePlayer:
            audioPlayer.pausePlayer(result)
            break
        case Constants.stopPlayer:
            audioPlayer.stopPlayer(result)
            break
}
  }
}
```

The `AudioPlayer` class

```
class AudioPlayer : NSObject,FlutterStreamHandler{
    var player: AVPlayer?
    private var sink: FlutterEventSink?

// I'm initialising it using method call before doing anything
func preparePlayer(path: String?, volume: Double?,result:  @escaping FlutterResult){
        if(!(path ?? "").isEmpty){
            let url = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: path!)
            player = AVPlayer(url: url)
                player?.volume = Float(volume ?? 1.0)
                result(true)
        } else {
            result(FlutterError(code: "", message: "Path to file can't be empty or null", details: nil))
        }
    } 

func startPlayer(result:  @escaping FlutterResult){
                do{
                    if(player?.status == .readyToPlay){
                        player?.play()
                       
                        result(true)
                    }
                } catch {
                    result(FlutterError(code: "", message: "Failed to start player", details: nil))
                }
    }

func pausePlayer(_ result:  @escaping FlutterResult){
        print(player?.currentItem?.duration.seconds)
        player?.pause()
        result(true)
    }

//Here it is being nil
func onListen(withArguments arguments: Any?, eventSink events: @escaping FlutterEventSink) -> FlutterError? {
 print(self?.player?.currentItem?.asset.duration)//<---prints always nil
        sink = events
       let interval = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.5, preferredTimescale: CMTimeScale(NSEC_PER_SEC))
//never goes inside because player is nil
        player?.addPeriodicTimeObserver(forInterval: interval, queue: nil, using: {[weak self] time in
            print(time)
           
            self?.sink!(0)
        })
        return nil
    }

    func onCancel(withArguments arguments: Any?) -> FlutterError? {
        sink = nil
        timer.invalidate()
        return nil
    }
}
```

Here when I call start player it does play the audio file. pause and stop also works.
Now when I call `self?.player?.currentItem?.asset.duration` inside `pausePlayer()`, it does give me the duration but when I try to print this inside `onListen()` function it always returns nil.

when I tried to print instance of `AVPlayer` which is `player` here, it also prints to nil.

So what am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I passed `AudioPlayer()` instance to `setStreamHandler` it was creating new instance of AudioPlayer for only stream so that why I was getting always `nil` so what I created a singleton so that it will only create a single copy.

```
class AudioPlayer : NSObject, FlutterStreamHandler {
    static let sharedInstance = AudioPlayer()
}
```

now in the handler,

```
public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
let durationChannel = FlutterEventChannel(name: Constants.durationEventChannel, binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
        durationChannel.setStreamHandler(AudioPlayer.sharedInstance)
}
```